# Copy bolded with Style output to Word

Tags: style

I have an simple bolded expression and it's output, say

[image]

Is there any way to keep the formatting that when making a copy of the output and pasting to word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do an ordinary select/copy in mathematica but you need to "paste special" and select "Formatted Text (RTF)" in word.

Comment: I have one more issue. When I use this technique to export String in which there is cyrillic it pastes those letters blank. Do you know a fix?